# mysql query where on a date an fk doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

So I have time sheet tables and what I am looking for is days where they did not take a lunch:

Lunches are indicated by earn_code_id 6

So what I need is employee_id's for dates that earn_code_id 6 did not exist.

```
SELECT employee_id FROM
TIMESHEET_dates t1
    JOIN
TIMESHEET_entries t2 ON t2.timesheet_id = t1.id WHERE t1.date_applied = "2018-04-16" and t2.earn_code_id != ????
```

Comment: "So I have time sheet tables and what I am looking for is days where they did not take a lunch:" "So what I need is employee_id's for dates that earn_code_id 6 did not exist." Hint: `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE t2.column IS NULL AND t1.date_applied....`  instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Can you add some sample and expected data? Say the structure of the tables?

Comment: Sample input???  Expected output???  Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask